# MySQLi: Selecting 5 most common data in column & returning in order for display

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to select the 5 most common words from a column called `favorite` from a table called `users`.  I only need the top 5 but would like them to return in order 1 to 5 for display.  These are names so for example:

```
user1    Bob Marley
user2    Stan Smiley
user3    Bob Marley
user4    Joe Schmoe
```

etc...

I have the following as a start:

```
$db_fav_query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT favorite, COUNT(*) AS favCOUNT FROM users GROUP BY favorite ORDER BY favCOUNT DESC LIMIT 5");
$db_fav_query->execute();

$db_fav_result = $db_fav_query->get_result();
$row = $db_fav_result->fetch_assoc();

$fav1 = $row['favorite'];
```

I'm trying to output as follows:

```
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($fav1); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($fav2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($fav3); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($fav4); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($fav5); ?></td>
 </tr>
```

I realize that `$fav2`, `$fav3` etc.. have not been declared, but am not sure how to fetch these from the dB so they can be assigned as such.  I'm not getting any errors, but right now `$fav1` returns nothing.

Comment: Your SQL query seems fine, can you enable error report to show any possible error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a while loop to loop through all the row

```
while($row = $db_fav_result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $fav = $row['favorite'];
  echo $fav;
}
```

to put them to a table:

```
<tr>
<?php
while($row = $db_fav_result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $fav = $row['favorite'];
  echo "<td>$fav</td>";
}
?>
</tr>
```

Comment: ...and here I thought it was my query.  Many thanks.